# local MAMP Pro redirect to https

Tags: https, safari, localhost, mamp-pro

I have installed Mamp Pro to run my local host and it has been working great for a year or so but recently when I start it up and go to one of my hosts it redirects to a https connection and throws an error:

"Safari Can't Open Page.  Safari can't open page because Safari can't establish a secure connection to the server."

It works fine in Chrome but Safari is giving me issues.  I've restarted my computer, restarted MAMP and nothing has worked so far.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are using .dev domains for local development ( mydomain.dev ) , try something else e.g. mydomain.local, mydomain.lcl

This happened to me with macOS 10.13.2, in both Safari and Chrome (63.0.3239.84).

After reading [this post](https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/), it seems a better choice to just change my .dev domains than mess with browser default settings.

Comment: I changed it to .local and it worked great!  Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately not working for me, before I post another question wanted to check here. It's not working in Chrome, FF, or Safari. MAMP Pro 5.2 + Browsers LTS. Really confused. ps. Not a "server-guy" by any stretch and I'm kinda at my wits end with this whole project. lol

Answer (score 4):

Do you have installed the update to MacOS 10.13.2? After upgrading to this version no website on localhost can be started. Every host redirects to a https connection.

Comment: Yeah I have 10.13.2 beta installed.